# Bash script: Unable to move a file to another directory

Tags: bash, syntax, ssh

I'm having an issue with my script. The variables X and Y are assigned the last octet of an IP address and work fine. Z is supposed to take X and Y and put the values into a new txt file.

```
X=$(ssh -i key.txt "$USER"@A.B.C.D "awk -F' ' '{print \$2}' /etc/openvpn/ccd/lastip.txt | awk -F'.' '{print \$4+4}'")
Y=$(ssh -i key.txt "$USER"@A.B.C.D "awk -F' ' '{print \$3}' /etc/openvpn/ccd/lastip.txt | awk -F'.' '{print \$4+4}'")
Z=$(ssh -i key.txt "$USER"@A.B.C.D "touch $NAME.txt | chmod 700 $NAME.txt mv $NAME.txt /etc/openvpn/ccd | echo -n "$X $Y" > /etc/openvpn/ccd/$NAME.txt")
```

I keep getting messages say permission denied:

```
mv: bash: /etc/openvpn/ccd/almost.txt: Permission denied
cannot move `almost.txt' to `/etc/openvpn/ccd/almost.txt': Permission denied
```

The directory exists and the permission for it are fine. How would I go about being able to move $NAME.txt into my desired directory?

EDIT: Even without Z=$() and using the command line, I still get permission denied errors

Comment: can you share output of `ls -ld /etc/openvpn/ccd/` ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2013-01-16 15:01

Comment: Well, there's your answer, only `root` can write there, so unless your `$USER` is `root` - you're out of luck.

Comment: Is that last line correct? It has multiple syntax errors. (1) Why is touch being piped to chmod? (2) There's no semi-colon between the chmod and the mv. (3) Why is mv being piped to an echo? (4) The double quotes around `"$X $Y"` aren't escaped.

Comment: I figured it did, I'm learning bash as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit needs some work:

```
touch $NAME.txt | chmod 700 $NAME.txt mv $NAME.txt /etc/openvpn/ccd | echo -n "$X $Y" > /etc/openvpn/ccd/$NAME.txt
```

At minimum, you need to replace the pipes with semicolons, and one of the spaces too:

```
touch $NAME.txt; chmod 700 $NAME.txt; mv $NAME.txt /etc/openvpn/ccd; echo -n "$X $Y" > /etc/openvpn/ccd/$NAME.txt
```

It does not look plausible that you want to execute `$NAME.txt`; you should not use 700 but 600 permissions.

Since you didn't have a semicolon before the `mv`, the `chmod` program tried to change permissions on files `mv`, `$NAME.txt` a second time, and `/etc/openvpn/ccd`.

Unless you are running as `root`, you should not be able to write in `/etc/openvpn/ccd`.  However, you have not shown us the permissions on the current directory, though since `touch` appears to have worked, you can presumably write in that.  Nor, at the time I wrote this, were the permissions on `/etc/openvpn/ccd` given — but see below.

---

And, as [John Kugleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) notes in a comment, in the larger context where the command string I dissected is inside a set of double quotes, the double quotes around `"$X $Y"` should be escaped with backslashes:

```
Z=$(ssh -i key.txt "$USER"@A.B.C.D "touch $NAME.txt; chmod 700 $NAME.txt; mv $NAME.txt /etc/openvpn/ccd; echo -n \"$X $Y\" > /etc/openvpn/ccd/$NAME.txt")
```

---

#### Source of 'no permission' error

Given that the permissions on `/etc/openvpn/ccd` are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2013-01-16 15:01 /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

we can infer that you are not running as `root` and are not permitted to write in the directory.  You may need to get permission to use `sudo` on the target machine.

Comment: Originally I had `chmod 600` but changed it trying to get this line to work. The file does get created and the permissions do change. I'll try this out right now

Comment: You're not the first to replace 6 with 7; quite often, in desperation, people replace 600 with 777, just in case.  Expect it to be commented on if you forget to undo it, that's all.  It's the security of your machine that's at risk, not mine, though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind about chmod now. My loggin is supposed to be root, maybe somebody overlooked something? Thanks for the answer!